# Uglify throws Parse error

Tags: gulp, gulp-uglify

When i use gulp-uglify with browserify i get a error

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (/home/rkmax/my-project/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:189:18)
    at js_error (/home/rkmax/my-project/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:197:11)
    at croak (/home/rkmax/my-project/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:656:9)
    at token_error (/home/rkmax/my-project/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:664:9)
    at expect_token (/home/rkmax/my-project/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:677:9)
    at expect (/home/rkmax/my-project/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:680:36)
    at /home/rkmax/my-project/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1222:13
    at /home/rkmax/my-project/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:703:24
    at expr_atom (/home/rkmax/my-project/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1152:35)
    at maybe_unary (/home/rkmax/my-project/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1327:19)
    at expr_ops (/home/rkmax/my-project/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1362:24)
    at maybe_conditional (/home/rkmax/my-project/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1367:20)
    at maybe_assign (/home/rkmax/my-project/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1391:20)
    at expression (/home/rkmax/my-project/node_modules/gulp-uglify/node_modules/uglify-js/lib/parse.js:1410:20)
```

this is my scripts task

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {

    var bundler = browserify({
        entries: ['./src/scripts/main.js'],
        debug: debug
    }).transform(stringify()); // the error persist even without this transformation

    bundler
        .bundle()
        .on('error', handleErrors)
        .pipe(source(getBundleName() + '.js'))
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default', { verbose: true }))
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('fail'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./web/js'));
});
```

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem, please either A) Accept the answer that solved it (possibly adding a comment saying how), or B) Post your own answer showing how you solved it. (Which is absolutely fine on SO, provided it really is distinct from the existing answers. SO will let you accept your own answer after 48 hours.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I encountered this same issue with `gulp-concat-sourcemap` and `gulp-uglify`. I solved it by ignoring map files with [gulp-ignore](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-ignore):

```
gulp.task("uglify-src", function() {
    gulp.src([ "src/js/**/*.js" ])
    .pipe(concat("app.js"))
    .pipe(ignore.exclude([ "**/*.map" ]))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/js"));
});
```

Answer (score 71):

`uglify` will parse the script content before minifying it. I suspect that one of the `browserify` source maps are being included in the stream down to `uglify`. Anyway to find the problem you can use [`gulp-util`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-util)'s [`log`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-util#log-msg) method to handle `uglify`'s exceptions. Example:

```
...
var gulpUtil = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    ...
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(uglify().on('error', gulpUtil.log)) // notice the error event here
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./web/js'));
});
```

If you still have problems fixing the issue, post the details after incorporating the error log.

Comment: not sure why it took me so long to find this... gulp-util helped me to pinpoint the error right away.. Thanks for posting this!

Comment: FWIW you can also do `.on('error', console.log)` probably not as concise as the above but I don't want another dependency, yet...

Comment: Unreal! Thanks! I had declared 2 variables using "let" ... I've been switching between Swift3 and JS :S

Answer (score 0):

It could be a simple error in your source JavaScript file.  Try disabling uglify by commenting it out in your gulpfile and see if your browser console spots the real issue.

```
gulp.task('minified', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.concatScripts)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())       
        //.pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', { addComment: false }))        
        .pipe(gulp.dest(publishUrl));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Errors are not propagated by Node.js pipe.  This article mentions @Marcos Abreu's `uglify().on` approach in addition to describing the use of `pump` instead of `pipe`.

https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify/blob/master/docs/why-use-pump/README.md#why-use-pump